# Using $(this) inside a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead.js method `typeahead` in multiple inputs and I need to add the selected value to a hidden input near the current input.

```
var $input = $('.typeahead');
$input.typeahead({
    ...
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        $(this).next('.input-hidden').val(item.id);
    }
});
```

But `$(this)` is not working in this case.

I created an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hvwy6a5n/

Comment: Can you check what `this` is pointing to. Also, if possible, share a sample as `JSFiddle` or `CodePen`

Comment: What about storing $input object globally, and user $input.next() instead of $(this).next()?

Comment: alert($input) is undefined?

Comment: or you can most likely just use `$input.next()` with no other changes

Comment: @Rajesh Guys, please see the JSFiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this: **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hvwy6a5n/2/)**.

Note, `.next()` will not work. Typeahead changes your DOM structure and you will need to navigate correspondingly.

- `this` represents `Typeahead`
- `this.$element.context` this will give you your current input.

This will give you next input

```
$(this.$element.context).parent().next().find(".typeahead")
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if `this` is referring to some-other object that the typeahead , or `this` is `undefined`. If it's not define (My guess) , then you need to bind this with `afterSelect`.

```
var $input = $('.typeahead');
$input.typeahead({
    ...
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        $(this).next('.input-hidden').val(item.id);
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: $(this) refres to an typeahead object. Please, see the JSFiddle example above.